# How big would the impact of a nuclear warhead be?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I am writing a post-apocalyptic science-fiction story which includes the detonation of a nuclear warhead. In this context, What scientific information is available about the impact of a modern day nuclear warhead?

Comment: It depends very much on weapon type, yield and method of delivery. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_nuclear_explosions There are several online calculators which can give you simulated damage maps etc. Some are linked at the wiki page, you can search for others.

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): This type of questions seems either to be _off-topic_ because the answer is easy to Google in the first place; or if OP wants extended information about the subject, it seems _too broad._

Comment: It's science fiction, you can make up the details.

Comment: -1 because the question doesn't show any research effort.

Answer (score 4):

As Olin said, there is no need to guess.

A resource that may be of assistance to you is the website ["The Energy from a Nuclear Weapon"](http://www.atomicarchive.com/Effects/effects1.shtml), this site breaks down the nuclear blast into approximate magnitude of each of the effects - including the blast, heat wave, radiation.  Also has a historical archive ad a library full of links to other sites.

*A side note: having been to Hiroshima, I got a very effective impression of how much an even small yield nuke can do.*

Comment: Thank you all very much for the information. You helped me a lot!

Comment: @Jargo you are most welcome

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to guess.  There have been sufficient above-ground nuclear explosions to know what impact they have.  See Hiroshima, Nagasaki, Bikini Atol, and many others.